# How to make minimum date compatible for .NET and SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

I am having an application in .NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2005.

There are lot of instances in my application where user is asked for date. There I found an error that whenever a user enters a date less than `01/01/1753` it gives the following error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

When, I drill down the error, I found that .NET supports dates from `01/01/0001` to `12/31/9999` whereas SQL Server 2005 supports date range of `01/01/1753` to `12/31/9999`.

Now I need to have check in my application for min date.

But the problem is that I have to implement it at lot of instances, so finding some better solution.

Can anyone tell me the other way round to handle this date issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Now you want min date as `01/01/1753` for all instances?

Comment: restrict application to SQL Server min date.

Comment: Yes i want the min date to be 01/01/1753, so that my application didn't crash

Comment: @MitchWheat : How can i do that, moreover, i have to do that at all instances, i need some function or way through which i can solve by some short method.

Comment: There is no good solution with SQL Server 2005. If you upgrade to SQL Server **2008**, use the `DATETIME2` datatype which supports the same date range as .NET does. But other than that, you'll just have to check your .NET code so that it never sends a date before 1753-01-01 to the database....

Comment: Why would you need dates < 01/01/1753 anyway?

Comment: @Magnus: i dont need those dates, but this check needed to save page crash and handle it.

Comment: @marc_s: thanks for the suggestion, but i cannot upgrade SQL as my client as lot more applications running on same database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this might help you to get a valid SQL DateTime easy

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime AsSqlValue(this DateTime date)
    {
        if(date < SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
            return SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
        return date;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
MyDateTime.AsSqlValue();
```

Comment: That can be of great help to me. Thanks @magnus